# I have a problem with dislike error when creating an pafy.new url, perhaps it's because youtube hid numer of dislikes

Tags: python, pafy

```
import pafy
import vlc
url = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h_D3VFfhvs4"
video = pafy.new(url)
```

KeyError: 'dislike_count'

Comment: The latest commit to https://github.com/mps-youtube/pafy is from 5 months ago. Its issues page (https://github.com/mps-youtube/pafy/issues) already has reports of that exact error; clearly that module is out-of-date. There's already a Pull Request with the fix, so you'll just have to keep track of it: https://github.com/mps-youtube/pafy/pull/305 In the future I suggest doing basic research like looking at the module's official pages and all that. All this info was trivial to find.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [backend\_youtube\_dl.py", line 54, in \_fetch\_basic self.\_dislikes = self.\_ydl\_info\['dislike\_count'\] KeyError: 'dislike\_count'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70344739/backend-youtube-dl-py-line-54-in-fetch-basic-self-dislikes-self-ydl-info)

Comment: please check this answer as it provides a working solution : [Solved pafy dislike_count error](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72417919/14000587)

Answer (score 11):

There's a less heinous solution than editing package files by using an older version of youtube-dl.

Just run `pip install youtube-dl==2020.12.2`

Answer (score 7):

just comment the line 53 and 54 from backend_youtube_dl.py in your pafy packages path

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: if you are using a virtual env then go to .venv\Lib\site-packages\pafy\backend_youtube_dl.py and comment out the 54 line

Comment: And if you are working with jupyter notebooks you need to restart your kernel to make those changes work with your code

Answer (score 1):

I face this same issue [solved]:

Here is problem screenshot:
[image: Key Error Pafy "dislike_count"]

How solve this issue?

1: Open `Pafy` package directory
[image: pafy keyword dislike_count issue]

2: Open `backend_youtube_dl.py` file in any txt editor

3: Add comment line number 54
[image: pafy keyword dislike_count solution]

[image: pafy dislike_count error solved]

Comment: good solve it work fine :) 

but I have docker image :(  your solution need to do manual work ...

Comment: I had to comment out likes and dislikes FYI (Jan 2023)

Answer (score 0):

Or you can replace these two lines

```
self._likes = self._ydl_info.get('like_count',0)
self._dislikes = self._ydl_info.get('dislike_count',0)
```

https://github.com/mps-youtube/pafy/pull/288